# Date Field from Flat file to sql server 2015

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a flat file with following data. I want to load to a date field. There could be nulls in the values. Can some body please help.

I have tried various ways. One way I did is to load first to a staging table in varchar(255) field. Then I try to load from staging table to a table with datetime field. I am struggling to use the dervied column to convert to datetime.

20191211072808
20200110195803

20191212033611
20191230214908

20200202082318

20200131020651
20200108023406

20200205162522
20191113005704
20200129130959
20200130161716

Comment: There is **no** SQL Server **2015** version out there - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 -  so which one are you really using??

Answer (score 0):

If you're confident that the format will always be eg 20200224112715, then the staging table approach will work, but you'll need to split the string into something that SQL can recognise as a date.

```
insert into [finalTable] 
select cast(left([dateField],4) + '-'  --year
+ substring([dateField],5,2) + '-'     --month
+ substring([dateField],7,2) + ' '     --day
+ substring([dateField],9,2) + ':'     --hour
+ substring([dateField],11,2) + ':'    --minute
+ substring([dateField],13,2)          --second
as datetime)
from [stagingTable]
where [dateField] is not null
```